# wacked a directory from the command line

Tags: macos, terminal, snow-leopard, command-line, bash

I was copying a file to /usr/local/bin from the commandline on a Snow Leopard Server 10.6 ... anyhow i typed the following ...

```
sudo cp ./le /usr/local/bin
```

Ouch ... that missed last forward slash from a bash shell screwed me. It wacked my directory with a copy of the le file renamed as bin. This is a pretty vanilla machine just used a fileshare. Any thoughts on how to recover? Noticed there is no lost+found ... err, at least I didn't see it in root directory.

Comment: Actually this should just copy `le` into `/usr/local/bin`, not overwrite it. Are you sure that you lost your bin directory that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to recover from that, aside from restoring from a backup. Command line utilities don't have an undo command (and they don't typically delete to the Trash).

lost+found wouldn't help either, since that is only used when a filesystem recovery utility has found filesystem corruption.

Answer (score 0):

What Brian said, you are in no return land.  To avoid such problems in the future add this line to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

(and restart bash)

this way `cp`, `mv`, `rm` and suchlike will ask you before they overwrite or delete something.  That has saved my bacon a few times.

Comment: This does not work in the general case... it will only work if you have aliases set up that cause those commands to ask confirmation.